# Incoming E-Mail Service on an App server

Tags: incoming-email

creating my first tiered and load balanced farm in SharePoint, working with 2013 and found that once i started adding App Servers to the farm, it was necessary to turn off "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" on my Application server or else it would allow content sites and pools to be host/created on the box i was soley using for services.

So i also noticed another service that i wasn't to sure about either..."Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail", does this service need to be running on my application server when it is running on my WFEs, I assume that email would hit those first and go where it needs to and that it was not necessary on my application servers which just host services to the farm.

Am i correct in this theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can safely stop the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" service instance on your application servers - it's not really needed. If those sites aren't hit by users the application pools won't even spin up. So no resources are being used.

The incoming email service instance can also be stopped on the application servers. If you're not using it at all you can also stop it on your web servers too. There are no physical services attached to this service instance so letting it run won't cause any harm either. To be able to use incoming email you would have to install the IIS SMTP server and configure DNS too btw.

Comment: Thomas this was helpful in sheding light into what I was curious about. Answers things well, Thanks!